# CustomValidator: is there a sample with complete source code including client-side code?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have seen articles explaining CustomValidator and client-side code with a few segments of C# code, but the code AS-IS did not compile.  I am looking for a sample with COMPLETE C# source code including the client-side code for CustomValidtor that can build and run in Visual Studio 2010 .

Answer (score 1):

There's a full example on the MSDN page for CustomValidator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx provides a few segments of C# code, but I cannot take the code AS-ID and build a web site.  I am looking for a sample with COMPLETE C# source code including the client-side code, that I can download and build without finding the missing pieces.

Comment: Did you scroll down? There's full source code for an entire page - ASPX markup, client side javascript and server side event handling. What more are you looking for?